# Winston does not write in the log files

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

Simple issue with the Winston logger for NodeJS, taking a ridiculous amount of hours to solve:

```
const winston = require('winston');

exports.logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            format: winston.format.json(),
            level: 'info',
            timestamp: true,
            maxsize: 512000, // ~ 5 MB
            maxFiles: 10,
            filename: '../logs/info.log'
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: winston.format.simple(),
            level: 'info'
        })
    ]
});
```

Just as a funny fact, it can create the file inside the folder if it exists, but cannot create the folder if it does not exists (WTF?).

The problem is that never saves any information to the file. I tried modifying the access privileges. Nothing. No feedback received anywhere about the issue.

I may be too dumb for the documentation because nothing is covered about this but many people seem to be facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just discovered the problem: depending on where the file is called from, the path will be interpreted differently.

**Diagnose:** The chunk I am showing was **not** in the project's root directory, but the main file I was executing is (and is requiring that chunk of code), and because of that the path was being interpreted from the root file's perspective.

**Result:** I was having my logs written right outside of my project's directory.